# What are the equivalent libraries for rt.jar and jfxrt.jar for the latest version of jdk17 and javafx17?

Tags: java, javafx, java-17, openjdk-17, javafx-17

I was tasked to upgrade an old desktop app using old java and it used `rt.jar` and `jfxrt.jar` libraries. I have searched online about the libraries(`rt.jar` & `jfxrt.jar`) but apparently, it is no longer there in Java 17 and  JavaFX 17. What are the equivalent libraries for `rt.jar` and `jfxrt.jar` for the latest version of Java 17 and  JavaFX 17?

Comment: What functionality of `rt.jar` do the app use?

Comment: I do not know actually as I am really new in java app development. They throw a really old java desktop app at me to upgrade and I am really lost right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding JavaFX and Java 17, you need to use a new JavaFX-specific SDK with all the necessary runtime dependencies here: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

Also, refer here to the starting place to learn more about JavaFX: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Note that `rt.jar` was removed as of Java 9, read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-A78CC891-701D-4549-AA4E-B8DD90228B4B

> Class and resource files previously stored in lib/rt.jar, lib/tools.jar, lib/dt.jar and various other internal JAR files are stored in a more efficient format in implementation-specific files in the lib directory.